# How to authorize wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a REST web service which perform some operation, before it do any thing it authorize the user, for that purpose it call one method which check

```
 if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] != null)
 {  
   string userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString();  
 }
 else
 {
   throw exception;
 }
```

I am calling this service in my asp.net web application like below

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        req.ContentLength = 0;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
        {
            req.ContentLength = body.Length;
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(body);
            Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            newStream.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse resp;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;

            //pass on the exception
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

How can i pass the userId.....

My service and my web application both are in same solution but in different project and userId's value is coming from database based on user who is log in in the application.

Comment: How/where are you setting the `UserId` in the `Session`?

Comment: yes i am setting userId in session. once i successfully log in.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAuth is a good route for this.

Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( userId );
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;           

 using( data = req.GetRequestStream() ) { 
                data.Write( postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length );
                data.Close();
            }
```

Comment: This is used to send data from body, How to send session 
?